# statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters ExponentialSmoothing model appears to use the same data and parameters but returns two different results

Tags: statsmodels, forecasting, holtwinters

I am using statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters ExponentialSmoothing to fit the model to a time series. I am performing grid search for parameters of trend, seasonal, and damped_trend. The rest of the parameters are estimated by the model. Because I noticed some odd behavior (as described here), I then re-use the same set of grid-search and estimated parameters to initialize the model for the same data and print the first and second set of fitted values. **This second set of forecasted values is **nearly identical** to the first set for all 8 combinations of grid-search parameters, **except one**, where it does not look anything like the initial fit. I would like to understand why this is happening?**

**The model and its output are specified as below:**

```
model = ExponentialSmoothing(
        df_train['y'],
        trend=config['trend'],
        seasonal=config['seasonal'],
        damped_trend=config['damped_trend'],
        initialization_method='estimated'
    ).fit()
print("Model parameters: ", config,'\n',model.params)  
#creating output dataset
proj_act = pd.DataFrame(model.fittedvalues, columns=["HWES"])
proj_forecast = pd.DataFrame(model.forecast(steps=val_period), columns=["HWES"])
proj = pd.concat([proj_act, proj_forecast])
df = df.reset_index().merge(proj.reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"ds"}), how="outer", on="ds")
```

**The re-initialization looks like this:**

```
model2 = ExponentialSmoothing(
        df_train['y'],
        trend=config['trend'],
        seasonal=config['seasonal'],
        damped_trend=config['damped_trend'],
        initialization_method='known',
        use_boxcox=model.params.get('use_boxcox'),
        initial_level=model.params.get('initial_level'),
        initial_trend=model.params.get('initial_trend'),
        initial_seasonal=model.params.get('initial_seasons')
    ).fit(
        smoothing_level=model.params.get('smoothing_level'),
        smoothing_trend=model.params.get('smoothing_trend'),
        smoothing_seasonal=model.params.get('smoothing_seasonal'),
        damping_trend = model.params.get('damping_trend'),
        remove_bias = model.params.get('remove_bias')
    )
#adding to the output dataset and printing
proj_act2 = pd.DataFrame(model2.fittedvalues, columns=["HWES"])
proj_forecast2 = pd.DataFrame(model2.forecast(steps=val_period), columns=["HWES"])
proj2 = pd.concat([proj_act2, proj_forecast2])    
print(df.reset_index().merge(proj2.reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"ds"}), how="outer", on="ds"))
```

**The discrepancy in the two forecasts occurs at this parameter setting:**

Printing model parameters:
Model parameters:
{'damped_trend': False,
'seasonal': 'Add',
'trend': 'Mul'}
{'smoothing_level': 0.1817857142857143,
'smoothing_trend': 9.999999999999999e-05,
'smoothing_seasonal': 0.12587912087912087,
'damping_trend': nan,
'initial_level': 4670610.211111108,
'initial_trend': 1.0019498382292253,
'initial_seasons': array([ -55119.00260417,  -14312.9921875 ,  164648.39322917,
-143115.60677083,  137116.09114583,  -54149.2734375 ,
57126.3828125 ,   26319.55989583, -300643.45052083,
131789.84114583,  -75055.81510417,  125395.87239583]),
'use_boxcox': False,
'lamda': None,
'remove_bias': False}

Printing intialization parameters:
{'Ini_trend': 1.0019498382292253,
'Ini_season': array([ -55119.00260417,  -14312.9921875 ,  164648.39322917,
-143115.60677083,  137116.09114583,  -54149.2734375 ,
57126.3828125 ,   26319.55989583, -300643.45052083,
131789.84114583,  -75055.81510417,  125395.87239583]),
'Ini_level': 4670610.211111108,
'Trend': 'Mul',
'Seasonality': 'Add',
'Damped': False,
'Alpha': 0.1817857142857143,
'Beta': 9.999999999999999e-05,
'Gamma': 0.12587912087912087,
'Phi': nan,
'Error_Percent_Weighted_Mean_Val': 1.8787153394783243,
'BIC': 2365.7625492513066}

**Output:**
[A dataframe with the original forecast in HW_x column and the re-initialized model forecast in HW_y column. The error column is the % difference of the original forecast from the actuals.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiB28.png)